# error building MFC application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I have this sdk from a company and I try to run their sample application but it doesn't work. Visual studio tells me :

## error Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]

I have chose the shared dll version in settings already !
I also tried to add #define  _AFXDLL at the top of stdafx.cpp but no effect.
I also tried with runtime library to MT and MD and both are not working

Also I don't have this problem when I run with x64 but it doesn't work because my lib is x86 so I HAVE to make it work on x86 .
What can be wrong?
I don't know this project at all or what is stdafx of I would rather not change anything in the project itself ( just settings )
( i am using visual studio 2015, windows 10)
Thank you ! :)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i found ^^ in the properties you changes are made only for a specific plateform so all my changes were made for x64 but i was using x86 :'(

haha all good now! :)